# android resource linking:nav_graph.xml

Tags: android, linker, resources

## android resource linking failed for me was nav_graph **

android resource linking failed for me was nav_graph
I added these codes to build.gradle.kts(:app) in dependencies

implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.1")

implementation("androidx.navigation-ui:2.7.1")

**